Spring application did not start before the configured timeout only on linux in proxy
I have an application that runs fine in a windows + VPN environment, but does not run in a Linux + Proxy environment.
I tried different solution found on internet, but nothing seems to work.
Log Windows
Log Linux
application.yml
These are the commands used to start the application:

Windows: maven spring-boot:start
Linux: maven -Dhttp.proxyHost=$proxyHost -Dhttp.proxyPort=$proxyPort -Dhttps.proxyHost=$proxyHost -Dhttps.proxyPort=$proxyPort -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=$nonProxyHosts spring-boot:start

The only difference between the two settings.xml is that on linux the file is configured with the proxy (the maven install download all the dependencies without problems).
I see connection pool is started of oracle.ucp on windows, but not on linux, so I think that could be the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.
I tried different things like increment the time of application timeout or remove the proxy, but the timeout changes nothing and without proxy I can't resolve the url of the wallet, so an error is immediately thrown.
